# Can you find cocoa beans out-of-jungle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Other than a jungle, where can you find cocoa beans? I'd think you could find them in dungeon chests etc, but from experience this doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: You definitely used to be able to find them in chests, (that was the only place you could find them for a long time,) but I'm not sure if that's still the case.

Comment: villager trading as well IIRC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to obtain cocoa beans in vanilla minecraft (Without spawning them in) is to:

Find them in dungeon chests (Including desert and jungle temples)

Harvest them from jungle trees

Trade for them with villagers (In older versions, cocoa beans are no longer included in the villager trade items)

Comment: So you CAN find them in structure chests? What about village chests?

Comment: According to the minecraft wiki on chest loot, you used to be able to find them in chests but this was removed in 1.6.1, so I believe this answer is currently correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can find cocoa beans from any chest that spawns in the world. Villages before 1.6 will trade beans to you and you can find them on trees.

Comment: Only before 1.6?

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach yes

Answer (score -4):

No, they only grow on jungle trees. :(

Comment: Unique username.

Comment: A quick peek at the accepted answer above shows that this answer is not correct.  Also, we tend to expect more robust answers here on this site.